# Avoid Proposer Slashing - Etherum2.0

Tags: eth-2.0, validators, slashings, slashing-detectors, attestations

According to specs, for proposer slashing i need to compare the slot with previous block.slot

my question is- is it enough to check that the current block slot is greater than the last block slot i saved to the hard disk or do i need to save all the slots since my first validator created?

Also, do i use the same data for all my validator clients (and their validators)? i mean if i actually can save only the last slot, i need to save the last slot for each validator or one for all of them (the maximal)?

I was based on this info:
https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/validator.md#how-to-avoid-slashing

Comment: That's two questions.  Please ask them separately.